# How to put captured regex group to OutputFilePath?

Tags: regex, node.js, brunch

is there anyway to put the captured regex group from outputFilePath value to outputFilePath in JoinTo Javascript?

In my brunch-config.js

```
javascripts: {
    joinTo: {
        '${1}.js': /app\/(\w+)\//
    }
  },
```

So if i have a sub folder name 'beta1', all the Js files in that folder will be merged to beta1.js (the sub-folder name)

But now, all js files in subfolders are in $1.js file.

Im using Brunch: 2.8.0 with Node: 4.4.3 and NPM: 2.15.1. Thank you.